# Run CMake's PACKAGE target from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I try to build a C++ project with CMake on Visual Studio 2017. So far the CMake support is quite convincing. However, how do I call the *PACKAGE* target introduced by *cpack*? Does anyone have an idea how to do this from within the GUI (it does not show up in the context menu of the *CMakeLists.txt* file). The *INSTALL* as well as the *BUILD_ALL* target show up in the context menu of the *CMakeLists.txt* file but the *PACKAGE* target is missing. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: ***it does not show up in the context menu of the CMakeLists.txt file*** I believe it should. I will check a project of mine that I have a nsis installer. Edit: Yes the `PACKAGE` target does show up in Visual Studio 2017 solution explorer in the `CMakePrefefinedTargets` folder.

Answer (score 1):

The default CMake `PACKAGE` target is only added by CMake if a file named `CPackConfig.cmake` exists in the outermost CMake build directory.

The `CPackConfig.cmake` file is usually generated automatically by CMake when the `CPack` module is included. It may however be generated under a different name, if the variable `CPACK_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE` is set before the inclusion of `CPack`.

Comment: The `CPackConfig.cmake` file exists in the cache directory but still there is no `PACKAGE` target in the solution explorer. Though, I have to admit, I do not even see a `CMakePredefinedTargets` folder as suggested by @drescherjm .

Comment: Turned out Eugen was using "Open Folder" in VS 2017. This does not show the `PACKAGE` target in the CMake menu.